# How to convert a string in float with a space - pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string

When I import an Excel file, some numbers in a column are float and some are not. How can I convert all to float? The space in `3 000,00` is causing me problems.

```
  df['column']:
             column
0          3 000,00
1            156.00
2                 0
```

I am trying:

```py
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(' ','')
```

but it's not working. I would do after `.astype(float)`, but cannot get there.
Any solutions? `1` is already a float, but `0` is a string.

Comment: I think this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas

Comment: 'but it's not working', what isn't working?

Comment: I already tried the to_numeric() but: Unable to parse string "3 000,00" at position 0 and I cant erase the space with replace above. Column values dont change and stay 3 000,00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast them all as a string first:

```
df['column'] = [float(str(val).replace(' ','').replace(',','.')) for val in df['column'].values]
```

**Example:**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'column':['3 000,00', 156.00, 0]})
>>> df['column2'] = [float(str(val).replace(' ','').replace(',','.')) for val in df['column'].values]
>>> df
     column  column2
0  3 000,00   3000.0
1       156    156.0
2         0      0.0
```

Comment: your exemple works, but when I try with my data, i get :could not convert string to float: '3\xa0000'. Maybe my import is wrong: df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

Comment: yeah, that sounds like you have a weird character or unexpected line break

Comment: Looks like either Excel or your source has worked weird characters into your data.  Remove those characters as well before converting to float: `.replace(u'\xa0', '')`

Comment: The only weird thing I see is that I also have values with -9 000,00 but it works in the example above. Im not sure what is the problem...

Answer (score 1):

```
import re    
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", str(x).replace(',','.'))).astype(float)
```